# Ошибка 0xc000007b при запуске тестовой программы в C::B с библиотекой SFML

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

Недавно поставил библиотеку SFML 2.5.0 для версии minGW 7.3.0 SEH ( в C::B выставлен соответствующий компилятор minGW). 
При попытке запустить тестовую программу, которая есть на офф. сайте (вот она соответственно):

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    window.clear();
    window.draw(shape);
    window.display();
}

return 0;
}
```

возникает следующая ошибка: 
[image: Ошибка]

Windows 64 разрядная, C::B версии 16.01, minGW и SFML 64 разрядные соответсвенно. 
Как исправить?

Comment: А в каком месте ошибка? И какой стек вызовов?

Comment: Прошу прощения но я не знаю что такое стек вызовов. Насчет в каком месте ошибка: как только запускается программа (т.е нажимается run) она сразу же выдает ошибку

Comment: Стек вызовов - это цепочка вызовов функций в текущий момент выполнения программ (обычно показывается в одноименном окне). Вместо Run запустите код под отладчиком. Он вам покажет и строчку, на которой произошла ошибка, и стек вызовов. А то сейчас совершенно непонятно, что там у вас происходит.

Comment: При запуске отладчика сразу же возникает эта же ошибка.

Comment: Хм, это странно. Возможно у вас имеет место какая-то бинарная несовместимость с библиотекой.

Comment: Лично мои подозрения это то что есть несостыковка с библиотекой
libstdc++-6.dll
UPD: но скорее всего это не так: я попытался подменить библиотеку 7.3.0 библиотекой 4.9.2, ничего не изменилось.
<br>UPD2: Я попробовал убрать библиотеку вообще, и что странно: ошибки об её отсутствии даже не появилось, что еще может быть проблемой - я даже не представляю.

Comment: Уж если вы пытаетесь что-то чем-то подменять, то что-то явно идет не так. Переустановите компилятор начисто, пересоберите SFML заново этим компилятором и потом пробуйте.

Comment: Уже всё, я создал новый проект и все заработало, похоже старый забагался, а как и почему - уже неважно, большое спасибо за помощь.